# MASM : How do you declare a string with carriage return?

Tags: string, assembly, escaping, masm

I would like to know if it is possible in MASM to write special character in string.

```
HelloWorld db "Hello World!\r\n", 0
```

Would be an intuitive way but it does not work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ASCII codes for CR and LF are 13 and 10, so:

```
HelloWorld db "Hello World!",13,10,0
```