# Assembly program (masm) to count coins

Tags: assembly, masm

So I am still pretty new to assembly language. I have been tasked with writing a 80x86 assembly language program (masm) to compute and display the total value of the coins in dollar and cents.

Input: The program reads the number of coins(pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters) from the user.

Output: The program displays dollars and cents for the total, as well as the number of coins, with three lines of message.

I may not use any division instruction. The data section must include four labels each of which is for a character string to prompt for the number of coin type

My code will find the number of coins and the total value, I'm just not sure how to output to multiple lines. Help or guidance is appreciated. Here is my code so far.

```
.DATA                       ;reserve storage for data
pennies                     DWORD           ?                                       
nickels                     DWORD           ?                                       
dimes                       DWORD           ?                                       
quarters                    DWORD           ?                                       
prompt1                     BYTE            "How many pennies do you have?", 0      
prompt2                     BYTE            "How many nickels do you have?", 0      
prompt3                     BYTE            "How many dimes do you have?", 0        
prompt4                     BYTE            "How many quarters do you have?", 0     
asciiIn                     BYTE            15 DUP (?)                              
resultLbl                   BYTE            "Coin Information", 0                   
resultText                  BYTE            

.CODE                       ;start of main program
_MainProc                   PROC
                        ;read ascii input for pennies, convert to 2's comp, and 
                        input           prompt1, asciiIn, 15                    
                        atod            asciiIn                                 
                        mov             pennies, eax                            

                        ;read ascii input for nickels, convert to 2's comp, and 
                        input           prompt2, asciiIn, 15                    
                        atod            asciiIn                                 
                        mov             nickels, eax                            

                        ;read ascii input for dimes, convert to 2's comp, and st
                        input           prompt3, asciiIn, 15                    
                        atod            asciiIn                                 
                        mov             dimes, eax                              

                        ;read ascii input for quarters, convert to 2's comp, and
                        input           prompt4, asciiIn, 15                    
                        atod            asciiIn                                 
                        mov             quarters, eax                           

                        ;
                        mov             eax, pennies            
                        mov             numCoins, eax
                        mov             pennies, eax            
                        mov             total, eax
                        ;
                        mov             eax, nickels
                        add             numCoins, eax
                        mul             nickel
                        add             total, eax
                        ;
                        mov             eax, dimes
                        add             numCoins, eax
                        mul             dime
                        add             total, eax
                        ;
                        mov             eax, quarters
                        add             numCoins, eax
                        mul             quarter
                        add             total, eax



                        dtoa            resultText, total       
                        output          resultLbl, resultText   


                        mov             eax, 0                                  
                        ret
_MainProc               ENDP                                                    
                        END
```

Here is the code for the included io macros.

```
output  MACRO  outLbl, outStr      ; display label and string
        pushad                     ; save general registers
        cld                        ; clear DF
        lea    eax,outStr          ; string address
        push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
        lea    eax,outLbl          ; label address
        push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
        call   _showOutput         ; showOutput(outLbl, outStr)
        add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
        popad                      ; restore general registers
        ENDM
```

Comment: Use a carriage return? HelloWorld db "Hello World!",13,10,0 - 13,10 is the carriage return for masm I believe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090605/masm-how-do-you-declare-a-string-with-carriage-return

Comment: Where do you get the macros - especially `output` - from?

Comment: I included the output macro. If you need more just let me know.